# Mark div objects as selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, interact.js

[This is my jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/meeqhud9/5/)

I want to be able to mark `div` objects as selected. These objects should have a class `draggable` (red circles).

Also, the selection can be applied to those circles that are inside div area that has a class `dropzone`.

```
div.draggable.selected {
    border:4px solid black;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    border-radius:3px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(".draggable").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    });
});
```

How can I do it?

Comment: That you are using interact.js is an important detail.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using interact.js, you should put such class manipulation into your interact event handles.  I was able to accomplish what I believe you wanted by adding the line `$(target).addClass("selected");` to the interact `onmove` like so:

```
onmove: function(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  $(target).addClass("selected");
  var x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.dx;
```

and then also to the `onend`handler:

```
$(event.target).removeClass("selected");
```

For a complete working example, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/weubd2yg/

Comment: Thanks. It looks nice. Just one thing. In your jsfiddle the circle gets selected when it is moved inside dropzone. I want to maintain a circle selected after clicking on it inside dropzone. When I click a send time, it should be unselected. How can I do it?

Comment: I need something like this: jsfiddle.net/meeqhud9/6. The only thing is that the selection should be only allowed inside `dropzone`.

Answer (score 2):

Your window.load function is being overwritten in your jsfiddle link.  If you instead place the `$('.draggable').click()` listener inside a docReady function, `$(function(){ //code });`, it will then be attached to that event as expected.

Also, rewriting the listener to `$(document).click('.draggable',function(){ //code });` will handle attaching this event to dynamically created .draggable elements, where as binding it to the existing .draggable elements on page load will not.

Comment: I followed your suggestion: http://jsfiddle.net/meeqhud9/6/ However now I should click twice in order to select an object. If I do `$(document).click('.draggable',function(){ //code });`, then it does not work at all.